# Why doesn't this layout work for Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml

**I am trying to make a simple greet friend app. in android Studio 3.0.1**

my XML code for **activity_main.xml** is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="hk.ust.cse.comp107x.greetfriend.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**and my code in main activity class is**

```
package hk.ust.cse.comp107x.greetfriend;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }
}
```

I still haven't completed by putting buttons and text boxes but I face a problem.

**When I see the preview of my app in emulator/ Virtual Device I get a grey screen inside a phone  [The Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQYxe.png) with** 
*Android...ActionBar Overlay layout*    written.

Am I doing something wrong here?

I'm new to XML so I don't get the lingo too much... 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Clean and rebuild

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry. You can run your app normally. 
Change your theme style in AndroidManifest.xml as following to make the preview works

```
<application
        .....
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Comment: @AkhilVaid could you vote up and mark my answer, I need 50 reputaion to comment

Comment: sorry but I have less than 15 rep. :D

Comment: @AkhilVaid now you have more 15

Answer (score 0):

these codes are correct. to solve this problem, find the "values" directory, then open "styles.xml".
change

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.*">
```

to:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's my first time trying to work in android studio and I was worried whether I had downloaded something wrong. This worked like a charm! :D

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you have not sdk downloaded for the platform your preview is using.Change platform of android preview screen.
[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTcqn.png)
I have sdk tools for 24 you can change it accordingly or you can download your platform tools by opening standalone sdk.

If this solution does not work then try to change theme of the activity in preview from beside of platform tool selection button.